# Other method other than integration by parts

Tags: calculus

I would like to integrate this
$$\int x \ln x\sin x\mathrm dx$$

can I do it with another quick method than using integration by part?

Comment: You'll have to integrate $\frac1x\sin x$ anyways.

Comment: It is not always possible to integrate by more than one way

Comment: Some Magic is helpful in this situation

Comment: Can you tell us you have a problem with integration by parts?  If you want to give up the best method you should have some reason for it.

Comment: I think this integral can not expressed by the known elementary functions: $$-i/2\ln  \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{ix}}-1/2\,\ln  \left( x \right) {
{\rm e}^{ix}}x+i/2\ln  \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{-ix}}-1/2\,\ln 
 \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{-ix}}x+1/2\,\pi\,{\it csgn} \left( x
 \right) -{\it Si} \left( x \right) +i/2{{\rm e}^{-ix}}-i/2{{\rm e}^{i
x}}
$$

Comment: But Mathematica shows that the answer to this integral contains a $Si(x)=\int \frac{\sin x}{x} dx.$ So this is clearly not expected to be doable by any method including the integration by pars!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fun but not very useful trick: if you know the antiderivative already, any integral can be computed using only $u$-substitution. Proof:

$$\int f(x) \, dx$$
Let $F'(x) = f(x)$.
$$u = F(x), du = f(x) \, dx$$
$$\int du = u + C = F(x) + C.$$

So for your integral, we see that it can be solved using the magic $u$-substitution

$$u = -Si(x) + \sin x + \ln x (\sin x - x \cos x).$$

We have

$$du = x \ln x \sin x \, dx$$
$$\int du = u + C = -Si(x) + \sin x + \ln x (\sin x - x \cos x),$$

as desired.

Comment: Don't entirely understand why this answer was downvoted. If the question is whether or not there was a nicer way to do it than IBP, then the answer is almost certainly that there isn't one. If the question is if IBP is the _only_ method to solve this integral, as I had assumed, then this shows that there is another way.